# Tableview reloads when delegate function is called from one View, not from another.

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a part of my app where a user can have different banks, and the user can redeem credits from the bank.

The problem I'm having involves three TableViewControllers:

1. BankTVC is a list of the user's banks.
2. AddBankTVC is a static Table View where the user fills out the bank info
3. BankDetailTVC is a view where you can look at the details of the bank, and redeem credits.

BankTVC gets the banks to list in viewDidLoad by calling a function in my model that returns all the banks. AddBankTVC is accessed by an Add button in the navigation bar. BankDetailTVC is accessed by tapping on the cell with the bank in it.

```
func loadBanks() -> [Bank] {

    let bankFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Bank")
    bankFetch.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "lastUpdated", ascending: false)]
    let loadedBanks = try! context.fetch(bankFetch)

    if loadedBanks.count == 0 {
        let sampleBanks = addSampleBanks()
        return sampleBanks
    }

    print("Loaded Banks")
    return loadedBanks as! [Bank]

}
```

BankTVC conforms to the BankModifierDelegate protocol, which requires it to have a function called bankWasModified(). This just reloads the banks from the model

```
func bankWasModified() {

    print("Bank was modified")

    banks = bankModel.loadBanks()

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

When bankWasModified is called from AddBankTVC, BankTVC updates with the new information cell. However, when bankWasModified is called from BankDetailTVC, the information is not updated in BankTVC when I return to it. However, when I dismiss BankTVC and then go back into it, the information is updated.

I know that the context is being saved from my console output. The context is saved, bankWasModified is run, the banks are reloaded. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: When you trigger your delegate method `bankWasModified` from your BankDetailTVC, "Bank was modified" printed? Also check if you are calling your delegate method once modified details are saved.

Comment: @Natarajan Yeah the output is "Context Saved" "Bank was modified" "Loaded banks". Same console output for both.

Comment: In your load banks function, do print("Loaded Banks\(loaded Banks)") and check if modified bank details are saved properly. If prints correctly, your problem should be in table view cell.

Comment: Ok so It is printing Save Context and not throwing an error, but when I printed the Banks the balance wasn't updated.

However when I go back out to the main menu and then back to BankTVC the data is updated. But the console printout doesn't make any sense. It is completely different, doesn't tell me any of the information, just gives me an entityID and an x-coredata:// url...

Comment: Make sure that you are using same managed object context.

Comment: They are, I only have one context atm.